# Display modal on axios call completion

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

EDIT: I posted the answer I ended up finding for anyone else who comes across this.

Trying to create a reusable bootstrap 5 modal child component within Vue3. To be passed an ID as a prop from the parent component, use Axios to perform an API call for data. Then render the modal on completion. However the modal always loads without the data (as an empty white box) and I have to close and reopen the modal to see any of the loaded information. Unsure how to force the modal to display when data is loaded fully, or load the data into the modal without refreshing the modal.

ProjectPanel.cs (child)

```
<template>
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="projectPanel"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <PulseLoader v-if="isFetching"/>
          <div v-else class="row">
            <div class="col text-center align-self-center">
              <img
                class="image"
                v-if="imageUrl === ''"
                :src="projectDetail.thumbnailUrl"
              />
              <img class="image" v-else :src="imageUrl" />
            </div>
            <div class="col h-100">
              <div class="text-start pb-2">
                <h1>{{ projectDetail.name }}</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="text-start pb-2">
                <h2>{{ projectDetail.createdTime }}</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="wording text-start">
                <p>
                  {{ projectDetail.description }}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <img
                    v-for="item in projectDetail.Images"
                    :key="item.id"
                    class="img my-2"
                    @click="imageUrl = item.imageUrl"
                    :src="item.imageUrl"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import ProjectDataService from "@/services/ProjectDataService";
import ProjectDetail from "./Projects/ProjectDetail";
import ResponseData from "./Shared/ResponseData";
import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ProjectPanel",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      projectDetail: {} as ProjectDetail,
      imageUrl: "",
      isFetching: true,
    };
  },
  components: { PulseLoader },
  watch: {
    id: {
      immediate: true,
      async handler(val) {
        this.projectDetail = {} as ProjectDetail;

        if (val !== "" && val !== undefined) {
          await this.RetrieveProject(val as string);
        }
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async RetrieveProject(id: string) {
      this.isFetching = true;
      var responseData = {} as ProjectDetail;

      // Retrieve Projects
      await ProjectDataService.getById(id)
        .then((res: ResponseData) => {
          responseData = res.data.data.project;
        })
        .catch((e: Error) => {
          console.log(e);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.projectDetail = responseData;
        });
      this.isFetching = false;
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

the parent calls the child component like so `<ProjectPanel :id="id" :key="id" />`

Comment: I'm not quit sure what is exactly the problem in here. I guess the modal didn't recognize the new loaded data. Try to setup a key for the modal what would get an random string to force the renderer to rerender with the new data. 
https://medium.com/emblatech/ways-to-force-vue-to-re-render-a-component-df866fbacf47

Comment: Tried attaching a :key to the top level div in the child component that gets updated when the id watcher is called. Also tried adding this.$forceUpdate to the watcher. Neither seem to cause the data to load in correctly. In the parent component I have a few tags that have. data-bs-toggle="modal", data-bs-target="#projectPanel" with a data value id which is passed into the ProjectPanel as prop. The modal loads empty first time around. Then if I open it a second time the correct data appears. However if I click another tag and change the data same behaviour occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this issue. The way I solved it was by pulling out the top most level of the modal and pulling it into the parent component like so.

```
<div
    class="modal fade"
    id="projectPanel"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <ProjectPanel :id="id" :key="id" />
  </div>
```

This resolved the modal data issue for me.